# Nvidia GT430 installed on Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty - xorg misconfigured

Tags: ubuntu, xorg

We are running Ubuntu 9.04 Jaunty on a PC with onboard graphics. We installed a new graphics card, NVidia ENGT430 and its drivers.

However after regenerating Xorg.conf, X11 will not load, giving the following error.

```
Fatal Server Error. No Screens found.
```

When running Xorg -configure, we get the following:

```
Number of created screens does not match number of detected devices.
  Configuration failed.
```

and the output Xorg.conf being:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
        Identifier     "X.org Configured"
        Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
        Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
        InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
        InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
        ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
        FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
        FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
EndSection

Section "Module"
        Load  "extmod"
        Load  "dri"
        Load  "dri2"
        Load  "dbe"
        Load  "glx"
        Load  "record"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Keyboard0"
        Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
        Identifier  "Mouse0"
        Driver      "mouse"
        Option      "Protocol" "auto"
        Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
        Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor0"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
        Identifier   "Monitor1"
        VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
        ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <I>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "UseFBDev"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                    # [<str>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"                  # <I>
        #Option     "FlatPanel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FPDither"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CrtcNumber"                # <I>
        #Option     "FPScale"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FPTweak"                   # <I>
        #Option     "DualHead"                  # [<bool>]
        Identifier  "Card0"
        Driver      "nv"
        VendorName  "nVidia Corporation"
        BoardName   "Unknown Board"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <I>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "SWcursor"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "HWcursor"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "NoAccel"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ShadowFB"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "UseFBDev"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                    # [<str>]
        #Option     "VideoKey"                  # <I>
        #Option     "FlatPanel"                 # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FPDither"                  # [<bool>]
        #Option     "CrtcNumber"                # <I>
        #Option     "FPScale"                   # [<bool>]
        #Option     "FPTweak"                   # <I>
        #Option     "DualHead"                  # [<bool>]
        Identifier  "Card1"
        Driver      "nv"
        VendorName  "nVidia Corporation"
        BoardName   "Unknown Board"
        BusID       "PCI:1:0:1"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen0"
        Device     "Card0"
        Monitor    "Monitor0"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     1
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     4
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     8
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     15
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     16
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
        Identifier "Screen1"
        Device     "Card1"
        Monitor    "Monitor1"
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     1
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     4
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     8
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     15
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     16
        EndSubSection
        SubSection "Display"
                Viewport   0 0
                Depth     24
        EndSubSection
EndSection
```

How can we solve this?

Comment: do you have the newest NVIDIA drivers installed?

Comment: Try gksudo nvidia-xconfig and then nvidia-settings.

Comment: You can also try this: $ sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg